# Cannot open minikube dashboard from the VM on my local machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-dashboard

I have installed minikube on my linux server on my Oracle VM. I have tried opening the dashboard, but I can't open it open on my local machine.

The process I follow:

1. minikube start
2. minikube dashboard

```
Enabling dashboard ...
Verifying dashboard health ...
Launching proxy ...
Verifying proxy health ...
```

3. After this, it gives me a url (http://127.0.0.1:44987/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:proxy/ )

When I tried opening this mentioned url manually on my local machine (Chrome or Firefox) it doesn't open.

Operating System : Windows

Driver: Docker

Answer (score 0):

If you can `curl http://127.0.0.1:44987` from the VM, then you need to open the (random?) port-forwarded address on your VM software (or Oracle Cloud?)

In other words, by default, the printed address is local to that Linux machine, not to your Windows host, and minikube doesn't know its running in a VM under Windows.